# innerHTML in function (Global variables?)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm struggling to get this working. The `dispatch()` function seems to be getting triggered (tested with the alert), but the `innerHTML` lines don't seem to work.

Also, `i` doesn't seem to increase despite the `i++` in the `onSubmit`.

Here is the function in question:

```
function dispatch(passengers,i,timesArray)
{
    alert('value of i is '+i);
    timesArray[i]=getTime();
        
    var avTime=getAverageTime(timesArrary);
        
    var throughput=passengers*3600000/avTime;
        
    if(i==0)
    {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Calculating...';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = throughput;
    }
    //and possibly a list (w/e)
}
```

And here is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0);" name="applesForm" onSubmit="dispatch(document.applesForm.numPassengers.value, num, times);i++;">
    <input type="text" name="numApples" id="numPassengers" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Press on Dispatch!"/>
</form>
```

Could this be a question of not being able to change global variables from inside the function?

Or, is there something wrong with the `avTime` or `throughput` lines which is making the function cease?

Comment: Your code contains a typo, timesArrary, which will cause the execution of the function to cease. Is the typo present in the actual copy of the code?

Comment: You might try walking the `alert` through your function, and seeing where it fails.

Comment: Thanks, the typo is gone. The function seems to be failing at `timesArray[i]=getTime();`, would this line not successfully change `times[num]`?

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0);" name="applesForm" onSubmit="dispatch(document.applesForm.numPassengers.value, num, times);i++;">
```

`i` is a global variable, but in `dispatch()` `i` is an argument which is not in global scope. Inside `dispatch()` it is in local scope of that function, and can't be increased in global scope. Hence I think your `onSubmit()`should be:

```
onSubmit="dispatch(document.applesForm.numPassengers.value, num, times);num++;">
```

Comment: Thank you, _i_ should only exist inside the function. But it's still failing.

Comment: Try to `return false` from `dispatch()` to prevent actual submit of the form.

Comment: Added `return false` though that wasn't the ultimate problem.

Comment: Still fails? So we'd like to see the code for `getAverageTime()` and `getTime()`, maybe the truth is in those functions :).

Comment: You appear to be mixing solutions - you're passing "num" into the function call, using "i" inside the function, but you added "i++" to the onsubmit instead of "num++" (though if it's global, one wonders why you're passing it into the function at all)

Comment: It appears the problem lies in `getTime()`, which is a standard function which needs to be done on an object containing the current date. Collin, you're right and I only did that because I thought it was a quirk of Javascript I was dealing with. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `getTime()` is not a standard function, rather it's a method of the `Date` object. Try `new Date().getTime()` instead.

Comment: @Furby Hmm... this poor english of mine... It seems you've already done as I suggested in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the variable being increased outside the function? Shouldn't it be inside the function and increased there?

Also, if num is global, you don't need to pass it as a parameter.

```js
// global
var num = 0;

function dispatch(passengers, timesArray)
{
    alert('value of num is ' + num);
    timesArray[num]=getTime();

    var avTime = getAverageTime(timesArrary);

    var throughput = passengers * 3600000 / avTime;

    if(num == 0)
    {
         document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Calculating...';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = throughput;
    }
    //and possibly a list (w/e)

    // increasing num here!
    num++;
}
```

Then your form could drop the increase in the variable, and the num from the call.

```html
<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0);" name="applesForm" onSubmit="dispatch(document.applesForm.numPassengers.value, times)">
```

Cheers, Apoc.